# Cannot put String? in Text needing String - pulling information from Firebase and new flutter seems to be stricter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am pulling the loggedInUser in another page, but regardless this returns a future which cannot be put into the Text() widget to return the current user email address.

I am expecting the Text(userEmail) to return the email of the logged in user but currently cannot figure out the future/awaits to get this to occur correctly... I took one of the bootcamps but naturally flutter has updated since I took it 2 weeks ago... Thanks for your help!!!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class ProfilePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final String userEmail = loggedInUser.email;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              height: double.infinity,
              width: double.infinity,
            ),
            Container(
              height: double.infinity,
              width: double.infinity,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                // padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                //     horizontal: 40.0, vertical: 40.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30),
                      width: double.infinity,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Text(userEmail,
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                          SizedBox(height: 5),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried pulling the information outside in a await/async but it still saves it as a String?

I am pulling the current user in another file as follow:

```
    class _HomeScreen extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
  }

  void getCurrentUser() async {
    try {
      final user = await _auth.currentUser;
      if (user != null) {
        loggedInUser = user;
        print(loggedInUser?.email);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

And the following above my stateful widget as well:

```
final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
User? loggedInUser;
```

Comment: where does loggedInUser get its value from?

Comment: @RandalSchwartz in another screen as follows:

`class _HomeScreen extends State<HomeScreen> {`
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
  }

  void getCurrentUser() async {
    try {
      final user = await _auth.currentUser;
      if (user != null) {
        loggedInUser = user;
        print(loggedInUser?.email);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
`

Comment: Please edit your original question with that code.  That code is impossible to read as a comment.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz I updated it, sorry about that!

Comment: "  getCurrentUser();"... DO NOT RUN ASYNC THINGS IN initState.  initState must be sync, and anything left incomplete before build starts will be that... incomplete.  Bad strategy.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz, I appreciate the help with this, although since I am new to coding I have no idea how to do this.. It used to work before the latest flutter update and cannot find code on the correct way to do things